# How to stop Blogger Blog converting in mobile site?

Tags: blogger, adsense

I have a blog and I am using Adsense. But my blog converts in mobile version while opening on a mobile device and I lost my original theme and ads too. How to prevent it ???

Answer (score 1):

So, on yoursite.com/robots.txt add the following:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow: /
```

Or you can try few other parameters to see if it helps.

Get more help at [reference link.](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/01/a-new-googlebot-user-agent-for-crawling.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can manage that in your blog settings. Follow below steps,

Settings --> search preferences --> Click on Edit link against to Custom Robot.txt and place the text which showed in below screenshot and SAVE.

[image: custome robot.txt]

Answer (score 1):

From your blog dashboard, Go to **Theme** > click on gear icon >  select **No. Show desktop theme on mobile devices.**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you must edit your template :
by removing this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

from the header of your template 
and remove or override your responsive css

That's all.